# How to use yiijasper?

Tags: php, yii, reporting, jasperserver

I have already followed the instructions here:

> https://github.com/cezario/yiijasper

but still getting this error:

```
Exception

Time limit exceeded, please try again

C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\protected\extensions\YiiJasper\JasperReport.php(387)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the code on GitHub.

Line 387 is where the exception is thrown in this method:

```
public function reportOutput($exportID,$pages = false){

    if($pages)
        $pages = ";pages={$pages}";

    if($this->isReady($exportID)){
        $this->req->get("/rest_v2/reportExecutions/{$this->requestID}/exports/{$exportID}{$pages}/outputResource");
        $this->req->send(); 

        return $this->req->getArrayResponse();

    } else
        throw new Exception('Limite de tiempo excedido, por favor intente de nuevo');
}
```

The exception is triggered if `$this->isReady()` evaluates to `false`. This is the `isReady()` method:

```
public function isReady($exportID = null){

    if($exportID !== null)
        $exportID = "/exports/{$exportID}";

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){

        $this->req->get("/rest_v2/reportExecutions/{$this->requestID}{$exportID}/status");
        $this->req->send();
        if(strpos($this->req->getResponse(),'ready') !== false)
            return true;
        elseif(strpos($this->req->getResponse(),'not found') !== false)
            $this->exec();
        else
            sleep(1); 
    }

    return false;

}
```

There is a loop that goes around 10 times. Inside the loop it tries to do something, sleeps for 1 second if it does not work, and then terminates. If whatever the loops attempt to do does not work it returns `false`.

In other words: The `Time limit exceeded, please try again` is an exception that tells you that the `reportOutput()` method failed. Looking at the code it probably has something to do with an HTTP request timing out and thus taking too long.